# Hoisting vs Scope Chain

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, scoping, hoisting

How come, in the first block of code, I get "Hello", but in the second block of code, I get undefined, then "bye"?

For the first block of code, I get that it is going up the scope chain to get the hoisted variable "Hello", which I get the expected result.

```
    var greet = "Hello";

    var sayHi = () => {
        console.log(greet);
    }

    sayHi();
```

However, I'm struggling to understand how come, if I declare the variable greet after the first instance of console.log, I get undefined first? Shouldn't the JS engine go up the scope chain to find "Hello" first?

```
        var greet = "Hello";

    var sayHi = () => {
        console.log(greet);

        var greet = "Bye"; 
        console.log(greet);
    }

    sayHi();
```

Comment: It doesn't go up, because it already finds `greet` in the current scope (the second one you declared, which is hoisted). It's still `undefined` at the time. If you use `let`/`const` instead of `var` (which you generally should), you would get an error for accessing within its TDZ.

Comment: Because the `greet` you're using in the second `sayHi` function is a **local** within that function, because you've declared it with `var`, which is hoisted to the top of the function -- but only the declaration, not the assignment, so you start out with `greet` having the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between declaration and initialization. Declaration creates the variable, initialization assigns it its initial value. The statement `var greet = "Bye";` contains both things, but only the declaration is hoisted.

Comment: This is **well covered ground** in previous questions and answers, there's no need to add more.

Answer (score 1):

In the second block after hoisting, it is executed as below. That's why you see `undefined` and then `Bye`.

```
var greet = "Hello";

    var sayHi = () => {
        var greet;
        console.log(greet);

        greet = "Bye"; 
        console.log(greet);
    }

    sayHi();
```

Within the function, it sees the `greet` variable is defined in its scope. It won't look up in the scope chain as you expect.

Comment: This is **well covered ground** in previous questions and answers, there's no need to add more.